# Check if all visible dropdowns are empty or not jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have five `checkboxes` that are connected to a hidden dropdown.

The hidden dropdown is shown when a checkbox is clicked.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chb1" class="chk-group" name="chb" value="chb1">
<label for="chb1"> 1 </label>
<select id="slct-1">
  <option value="">Default</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value=3>3</option>
</select><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="chb2" class="chk-group" name="chb" value="chb2">
<label for="chb2"> 2 </label>
<select id="slct-2">
  <option value="">Default</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value=3>3</option>
</select><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="chb3" class="chk-group" name="chb" value="chb3">
<label for="chb3"> 3 </label>
<select id="slct-3">
  <option value="">Default</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value=3>3</option>
</select><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="chb4" class="chk-group" name="chb" value="chb4">
<label for="chb4"> 4 </label>
<select id="slct-4">
  <option value="">Default</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value=3>3</option>
</select><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="chb5" class="chk-group" name="chb" value="chb5">
<label for="chb5"> 5 </label>
<select id="slct-1">
  <option value="">Default</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value=3>3</option>
</select><br>
```

I want to check if all the visible dropdown is empty or not.

I have tried this code below, its working but its not what its supposed to do,

**Result of this code is** - 
When I select checkbox 1, 2, and 3, then changed the dropdown select of 3 it immediately returns true even if the dropdown select of 1 and 2 is empty.

**Expected Result** - 
It should only return true when all visible dropdown is not empty.

Here's the Code

```
$('input[name="chb"]').click(function(){
    checker();
  $('select[id^="slct-"]').change(function () {
      checker();
  });

});


function checker() {
  $('input[name="chb"]:checked').each(function () {
        var idnum = $(this).prop('id').replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        if (idnum != 1 || idnum != 2 || idnum != 19) {
            if ($('#slct-' + idnum + ' option:selected').val() === "") {
                $('span#text').text('False');
            } else if ($('#slct-' + idnum + ' option:selected').val() != "") {
                $('span#text').text('True');
            }
        }
   });
}
```

Here's the link for the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Lewie/pen/ExVzqvN?editors=1010) to try this code out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the logic actually .

The if-else statement here :

```
if ($('#slct-' + idnum + ' option:selected').val() === "") {
                $('span#text').text('False');
            } else if ($('#slct-' + idnum + ' option:selected').val() != "") {
                $('span#text').text('True');
            }
```

is actually iterating around all the checked checkboxes , but the text is displayed as true or false **finally** after only the **last** `select` value !

So in this case, a suggestion may be to make a `flag counter` that is incremented whenever `$('#slct-' + idnum + ' option:selected').val() != ""` .

Then, if the `flag` is equal to number of checked checkboxes, then display "True" **ONCE** after the each loop has ended, as follows: `$('span#text').text('True');`
And false otherwise similarly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using JQuery `each` and writing value to output i.e., `span#text` in every iteration, this will overwrite value in each iteration and the last value will get overwrited finally. One of the simplext fix I think here is :

```
    var i=0;
     for i = 0, $('input[name="chb"]:checked').length {
          if ($('#slct-' + idnum + ' option:selected').val() !== "") 
                   break;
    }
    if( i=== $('input[name="chb"]:checked').length)
   {
        print true
        return 
    }else {
    print false;
    }
   }
```

Here for loop will break if it has found non empty value. If all values are empty then after for loop completes value of i will be equal to length of array otherwise for loop has breaked on between due to non-empty value in one of the dropdown.